# not return count = 0 if value is null - oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqlcl

I'm trying to write a oracle SQL query to return if the values are not present then return the count as zero.

My query :

```
select company,
       sum(case when company IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO') then 1 else 0 end) count 
from   table_name
where  trunc(msg_date) = trunc(sysdate)
group by soc_id;
```

Actual output

| COMPANY | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| DEF | 2 |
| GHI | 3 |
| JKL | 7 |

Expected Output:

| COMPANY | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| DEF | 2 |
| GHI | 3 |
| JKL | 7 |
| MNO | 0 |

Expected Output doesnot print any values of 'MNO' company. Is there any chance, we have oracle SQL query to solve this issue ?

your response is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a table that lists the company names? Also, what if the output of your query also includes a company not in your list, e.g. PQR? Would you want that shown in your output as well as the non-existent MNO company?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TotalListOfCompanyNames.Company AS CompanyName, ISNULL(CountCompanyNameList.CountCompanyName,0) AS RecordCount
FROM table_name TotalListOfCompanyNames
LEFT  JOIN (
SELECT CountCompanyName.CompanyName, COUNT(*) CountCompanyName
FROM table_name CountCompanyName
WHERE trunc(CountCompanyName.msg_date) = trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY CountCompanyName.CompanyName
) CountCompanyNameList
ON TotalListOfCompanyNames.CompanyName = CountCompanyNameList.CompanyName
WHERE CountCompanyName.Name IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO')
```

You need the total list of company names to show a row where data does not exist (msg_date <> sysdate) for counts and left join this to the count of records for each company where msg_date = sysdate... ISNULL (NULL, VALUE) is a T-SQL function replacing NULL with VALUE.
Where no matching row is, count will be NULL and be replaced with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------
24.01.2024

SQL> create table table_name (company, msg_date) as
  2    (select 'ABC', date '2024-01-24' from dual union all  -- only this row satisfies condition
  3     select 'ABC', date '2023-12-31' from dual union all  -- isn't equal to sysdate
  4     select 'DEF', date '2024-01-01' from dual            -- isn't equal to sysdate
  5    );

Table created.
```

If you want to display *all* companies (regardless of result of the `count` function and whether `msg_date` is (or is not) equal to sysdate), you'll need

- list of all companies (that's what CTE does)
- outer join it to "original" table you have, paying attention to join conditions

  - date condition should be in join as well; if you move it into `where` clause, it'll "remove" companies that don't satisfy condition

So:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     all_companies (company)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT DISTINCT company
  5           FROM table_name)
  6    SELECT a.company, COUNT (b.company) cnt
  7      FROM all_companies a
  8           LEFT JOIN table_name b
  9              ON     a.company = b.company
 10                 AND TRUNC (b.msg_date) = TRUNC (SYSDATE)
 11  GROUP BY a.company
 12  ORDER BY a.company;

COM        CNT
--- ----------
ABC          1
DEF          0

SQL>
```

If date condition was moved into `where`:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     all_companies (company)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT DISTINCT company
  5           FROM table_name)
  6    SELECT a.company, COUNT (b.company) cnt
  7      FROM all_companies a LEFT JOIN table_name b ON a.company = b.company
  8     WHERE TRUNC (b.msg_date) = TRUNC (SYSDATE)          --> here
  9  GROUP BY a.company
 10  ORDER BY a.company;

COM        CNT
--- ----------
ABC          1
                            --> see? No DEF any more    
SQL>
```